# How to resize images on simplepie

Tags: php

I have a script which gets rss feeds but some images larger and take too much space.How to resize image size I've tried with this class but without success:

https://github.com/Nimrod007/PHP_image_resize

I've included and call the function

Here's the piece of code from script:

```
if (!empty($image)) {


/*here's the calling resize function*/
    smart_resize_image(null , file_get_contents($image), 300, 300, false , $resizedFile , false , false ,100 );



                $filetype = strtolower(substr(strrchr($resizedFile,'.'),1));
                if (!in_array($filetype,array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif'))) {
                $filename = ''; 
                } else {
                $filename = 'image_'.time().'_'.rand(0000000,99999999).'.'.$filetype;

                $up = file_put_contents('../uploads/newss/'.$filename,file_get_contents($resizedFile));
                $size = filesize('../uploads/newss/'.$filename);
                list($width) = getimagesize('../upload/news/'.$filename);
                if(intval($size) >= 1024 AND $width >= 40) {
                $filename = $filename;
                } else {
                unlink('../uploads/newss/'.$filename);
                $filename = ''; 
                }
                }
                } else {
                $filename = '';
                }
```

Comment: what's the issue? Do you get an error?

Comment: @dgig Yes images not saving to folder!

Comment: I have never seen parameter passed like this: ImageResize($up = file_put_contents('../uploads/newss/'.$filename,file_get_contents($resizedFile)));  Which parameters is ImageResize supposed to take in the documentation?

Comment: @dgig sorry this is old I've tried something different!